# How to replace a section of an array with another array [numpy]

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy

I'm trying to replace a section of an array with another array as follows:

```
data[1:-1,1:-1,1] = tmp_data
```

`data[1:-1,1:-1,1]` and `tmp_data` are both of the same size. I'm getting this error message:

```
TypeError: 'tuple' object does not support item assignment
```

Why is this happening? How can I fix it? Thanks

Comment: `data` appears to be a tuple, not an array.

Comment: `print(type(data[1:-1,1:-1,1]))` yields in `<class 'numpy.ndarray'>` And  then the program stops at that same line with `TypeError: tuple indices must be integers or slices, not tuple`

Comment: That... doesn't make sense. Are you saying that the `print` prints `<class 'numpy.ndarray'>`, and then *that `print` line* produces a TypeError? That's straight-up impossible.

Comment: I dont understand it either, but that is happening.
`print(type(data[1:-1,1:-1,1]))`   `TypeError: tuple indices must be integers or slices, not tuple` But it still prints `<class 'numpy.ndarray'>` Any idea on how to solve the problem anyway?

Comment: Is this in a loop? It sounds like there's a loop, `data` has a different type on different iterations, and you're not properly distinguishing what happens on which iteration.

Answer (score -1):

As size of both the arrays are same.
data[1:-1,1:-1,1] = tmp_data will not work out.
you need to provide the size of tmp_data that will fix into the assignment index.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.arange(20).reshape(2,2, 5)
>>> b = np.arange(21,41).reshape(2,2, 5)
>>> a[0:1,0:1,1]=b[0:1,0:1,1]
>>> a
array([[[ 0, 22,  2,  3,  4],
        [ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9]],

       [[10, 11, 12, 13, 14],
        [15, 16, 17, 18, 19]]])
```